# In the AT42QT1245 touch sensor controller, how do the buttons wire to the device?

Tags: diodes, matrix, touch-panel

Referring to the datasheet wiring diagram, page 4 here: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/Atmel-9632-AT42-QT1245_Datasheet-1368898.pdf

It simply says "Matrix X Drive" and "Matrix Y Scan In". Could someone clarify where exactly the touch buttons would connect to what pins, and if a diode is necessary where it would be placed?

The capacitive buttons only have a single pin. If I'm correct, button 1 would connect to X0 and Y0A, button 2 to X1 and Y0A, etc. But I can't say for certain how things are to be wired properly and to prevent issues if multiple buttons are pressed at once.

Comment: It's a 3x8=24 keys matrix. Isn't that clear from page 4 as well as page 1 where they say "24 keys"? There discussion of key outlines and how you might test settling time and make adjustments. I've not considered using such an IC, but it looks intriguing now that I've seen the IC. I'm curious about using it to drive a "dance pad" of my own design, now. Anyway, it doesn't look complex to me and they even include "adjacent key suppression (AKS) technology that can be selected on a per-key basis. AKS technology permits the suppression of multiple key presses based on relative signal strength."

Comment: I understand it is a matrix, that is why I am using it. I'm looking for some clarification on the key connections and diodes.

Comment: Page 1. Read it. I think it's clear enough.

Comment: @user11015833 what diodes are you talking about? ... page 5 shows a cross section of a button ... the touch point would be near the middle

Comment: @jsotola many button multiplexing examples I've seen have included diodes to prevent cross talk between buttons, but I am not sure about the capacitive surface having only 1 pin (instead of a button having 2 pins). But perhaps it is unnecessary with the chip handling it.

Comment: it is unclear of diodes would work to prevent ghost touch detection ... the capacitive buttons have two connections

Comment: https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/atmeltouch-dlg-dialog-configurator-avrtouchqtouch-component-ad?version=19.1

Comment: Dioes would absolutely short out the matrix and it would fail to work. As this is a matrix, there are both row electrodes and column electrodes, and at the button the capacitance between row and column is sensed for changes. Go to manufacturer web page and download application notes how to make a good PCB layout for a matrix button.